# Zxing library can't decode color photos [WP8]

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, zxing, qr-code

I want to decode qr code from photo from gallery. if i pick a photo that contains only QR code it works, but if it is a normal photo with qr in it the result is null. what i am doing wrong?

```
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

            BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader {AutoRotate = true, TryHarder = true};
            Result result = reader.Decode(wb);
```

ps. I tried to decode the luminance source this way:

```
            var writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
            writeableBmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(writeableBmp.PixelWidth, writeableBmp.PixelHeight);
            e.ChosenPhoto.Position = 0;
            writeableBmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            LuminanceSource ls;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[writeableBmp.PixelHeight * writeableBmp.PixelWidth];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = e.ChosenPhoto.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                ls = new RGBLuminanceSource(ms.ToArray(), writeableBmp.PixelWidth, writeableBmp.PixelHeight,
                    RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.Gray8);

            }
```

but if i do so it can't read even qr code that worked earlier.